# C# Task WhenAll, associating tasks by some variable

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, system.reflection

I'm trying load all my embedded resources in one go async.

Here's what I have:

```
   private static async Task<String[]> GetResourcesAsync()
    {
        var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

        var todo = new List<Task<string>>();

        foreach (var res in asm.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            using (Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(res))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                todo.Add(reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            }
        }

        return await Task.WhenAll(todo);
    }
```

But the problem with this approach is I have no way of knowing what resource corrosponds to which string in the array.

How would I go about associating each task to a resource name 'res'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that async doesn't accomplish much in your scenario. GetManifestResourceStream returns a stream that only supports synchronous operations because it reads directly from memory.

Comment: Good point, well that's one way of solving it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Dictionary<string, Task<string>>` for the `todo` collection (the `res` variable is a `string`) and you can add to the dictionary like this: `todo.Add(res, reader.ReadToEndAsync());`

After that you get the res-task pairs when you foreach on this dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up just rolling this sync as per [Michael Liu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127114/michael-liu) comment

> GetManifestResourceStream returns a stream that only supports synchronous operations because it reads directly from memory

So yeah...

```
    private Dictionary<string, IView> GetViewsFromAssembly()
    {
        var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

        var views = new Dictionary<string, IView>();

        foreach (var res in asm.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            using (Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(res))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                views.Add(res, new View(reader.ReadToEnd()));
            }
        }

        return views;
    }
```